# NGINX proxy pass alter location path

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

It was like a "wildcard" proxy pass situation,  In the original url first 3 parts are for the future didn't consider it for now, i just need to consider last 2 parts for proxy pass

For example the url is like `mydomain.com/asia/sreelanka/1011/clnt0023/configv2567.json` ,
I wanted to proxy pass to `otherdomain.com/clnt0023/configv2567.json` .

What i tried is

```
location ~ ^/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\/([A-Za-z0-9._]+) {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass https://otherdomain.com;
    }
```

This proxy pass the entire url to `otherdomain.com`. I wanted to remove first 3 parts of the url path of original url and proxy pass.

Actual url

```
mydomain.com/<random-string>/<random-string>/<random-integer>/<random-string-clint-id>/<random-file>
```

it need to proxy pass to

```
otherdomain.com/<random-string-clint-id>/<random-file>
```

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^/[A-Za-z0-9]+/[A-Za-z0-9]+/[0-9]+(/[A-Za-z0-9]+/[A-Za-z0-9._]+)$ $1 break;`

Comment: @RichardSmith does nginx rewrite route traffic one url to another in the "same server"? is proxy pass to different server is possible with this? i will try this one also and update.

Comment: The `rewrite...break` will modify the requested URL and continue to process the request within the **same** `location` block - which ultimately means the `proxy_pass` gets invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Richard Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862445/richard-smith)

This does the job.

```
rewrite ^/[A-Za-z0-9]+/[A-Za-z0-9]+/[0-9]+(/[A-Za-z0-9]+/[A-Za-z0-9._]+)$ $1 break;

location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass https://otherdomain.com;
}
```